# How to catch exceptions in initialization section of Units in Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I have a third party unit, witch raises an exception in initialization section of unit. How can I catch this exception on my application?

Comment: David will probably have the answer :) I am guessing that you can hook something in by adding your "catch" unit in before the third party unit in the list uses list. It must be possible because libraries like MadExcept and EurekaLog hook into the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot catch such a thing. The RTL executes the initialization sections and the rules are that no exceptions are to be raised. If exceptions are raised, then the fault is terminal.

Another way to thing about this is that when the initialization sections start to be executed, the language exception handling framework is not yet in place. That itself is installed as part of the RTL initialization.

The solution is to fix the code so that it obeys the rules. No exceptions raised in initialization sections.

---

Well, I suppose that you could hook the RTL code that executes initialization and perhaps replace that RTL code with exception resilient code. But what would be the point? If an initialization section raises an exception, the only sane assumption to be made is that the unit is not initialized and so not fit for use. Please don't try to bury your head in the sand and ignore the real problem. Fix the third party code.

Comment: @RezaRahmati I didn't think about this last part but it is really important. The moment you ignore the exception then you can't guarantee any code that is executed by your application that uses this library will be operating as expected. These sort of things have a habit of being forgotten and biting very hard down the line when you least expect it.

Comment: "You cannot catch such a thing." - maybe more correct "you should not catch such things", but in general i agree with David. Note from docwiki.embarcadero: Raising an exception in the initialization section of a unit may not produce the intended result. Normal exception support comes from the SysUtils unit, which must be initialized before such support is available. If an exception occurs during initialization, all initialized units - including SysUtils - are finalized and the exception is re-raised. Then the exception is caught and handled, usually by interrupting the program.

Comment: You can't even (just tried) hook into Application.OnException in one of your own UNITs (that must be loaded before the UNIT that causes an exception) - probably because "all initialized units - including SysUtils - are finalized and the exception is re-raised.". The Application.OnException handler is never called. So it appears that without some serious hacking, you can't do it. That being said, I agree with the other sentiments described here - such an exception (in an initialization of a UNIT) should always lead to process termination as the resulting condition of the program is undefined...

Comment: @HeartWare You can only do it if you hook `InitUnits` in `System`. A code hook would get the job done. Not a good idea mind.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn Without hacking you cannot catch it. The asker wants to catch the exception outside the third party unit.

Comment: @David I supposed there should be some standard way to catch it (ApplicationHandleException or something similar), but seems you right, all this standard methods can not be used in this case.

Comment: Thanks for reponse,The third party I am using is just "blocking country code" and if I add this unit, the app will be closed in that countries, I just want to get rid of it. Any solution?

Comment: Fix the code of this third party library so that it doesn't raise exceptions in its initialization code

Comment: You can catch it by replacing RaiseExceptionProc in an initialization section of a unit that's placed prior to the 3rd party unit. I have no idea if it would do any good though..

Answer (score -2):

You could try the OnExceptionEvent of the class TApplicationEvents, but I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnException) when you're not sure: *"OnException only handles exceptions that occur during message processing."*.